# How to write a fixed comment in an emacs buffer, respecting the mode?

Tags: emacs, comments

I want to write a little function to enter a fixed comment string such as the following on a new line, respecting the mode, e.g. in elisp I would like it to write

```
;; this is a comment
```

on the next line; and in C I would like it to write

```
/* this is a comment */
```

on the next line, and so on. How to do this? Maybe comment-dwim is useful but I don't know how to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `comment-dwim`:

```
(defun this-is-a-comment ()
  (interactive)
  (move-end-of-line nil)
  (newline)
  (comment-dwim nil)
  (insert "this is a comment"))
```